# jQuery function to get all unique elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

[jQuery.unique](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) lets you get unique elements of an array, but the docs say the function is mostly for internal use and only operates on DOM elements. Another SO response said the `unique()` function worked on numbers, but that this use case is not necessarily future proof because it's not explicitly stated in the docs.

Given this, is there a "standard" jQuery function for accessing only the unique values — specifically, primitives like integers — in an array? (Obviously, we can construct a loop with the `each()` function, but we are new to jQuery and would like to know if there is a dedicated jQuery function for this.)

Comment: @Future_Readers - While checking Rubyrider's answer, be aware that you may see unexpected results in using it - it is not a safe or reliable solution.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use `array.filter` to return the first item of each distinct value-

```js
var a = [ 1, 5, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 3, 2, 4 ];

var unique = a.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
    return i == a.indexOf(itm);
});

console.log(unique);
```

If supporting IE8 and below is primary, don't use the unsupported `filter` method.

Otherwise,

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function(fun, scope) {
        var T = this, A = [], i = 0, itm, L = T.length;
        if (typeof fun == 'function') {
            while(i < L) {
                if (i in T) {
                    itm = T[i];
                    if (fun.call(scope, itm, i, T)) A[A.length] = itm;
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
}
```

Comment: WARNING: The above code BREAKS in IE8 and below, which do not have native support for either `Array.filter` or `Array.indexOf`. See my revision of this answer for code that doesn't break in jquery-supported browsers.

Comment: Support starts in IE9, for more information visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: or use one of the many EcmaScript 5 shims, like [this one by Kriskowal](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Comment: @cwolves' answer should be the accepted one. This answer, and almost all the others, runs in O(n^2) time and will be **very, very** slow if you try it on a big array.

Comment: jquery.unique is depricated by JQuery 3.0, use uniqueSort() instead of: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Answer (score 54):

Just use this code as the basis of a simple JQuery plugin.

```
$.extend({
    distinct : function(anArray) {
       var result = [];
       $.each(anArray, function(i,v){
           if ($.inArray(v, result) == -1) result.push(v);
       });
       return result;
    }
});
```

Use as so:

```
$.distinct([0,1,2,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 14):

Based on @kennebec's answer, but fixed for IE8 and below by using jQuery wrappers around the array to provide missing Array functions `filter` and `indexOf`:

$.makeArray() wrapper might not be absolutely needed, but you'll get odd results if you omit this wrapper and JSON.stringify the result otherwise.

```js
var a = [1,5,1,6,4,5,2,5,4,3,1,2,6,6,3,3,2,4];

// note: jQuery's filter params are opposite of javascript's native implementation :(
var unique = $.makeArray($(a).filter(function(i,itm){ 
    // note: 'index', not 'indexOf'
    return i == $(a).index(itm);
}));

// unique: [1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, change the filter to be:  return i == $.inArray(itm, a);

Answer (score 10):

I would use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq), which provides  a `uniq` method that does what you want.

Answer (score 7):

```
    // for numbers
    a = [1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8, 1,1,4,5,6]
    $.unique(a)
    [7, 6, 1, 8, 3, 2, 5, 4]

    // for string
    a = ["a", "a", "b"]
    $.unique(a)
    ["b", "a"]
```

And for dom elements there is no example is needed here I guess because you already know that!

Here is the jsfiddle link of live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3BtMc/4/

Comment: But the documentation says that $.unique() *only* works on DOM elements! "Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers." -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/

Answer (score 6):

Walk the array and push items into a hash as you come across them.  Cross-reference the hash for each new element.

Note that this will ONLY work properly for primitives (strings, numbers, null, undefined, NaN) and a few objects that serialize to the same thing (functions, strings, dates, possibly arrays depending on content).  Hashes in this will collide as they all serialize to the same thing, e.g. "[object Object]"

```
Array.prototype.distinct = function(){
   var map = {}, out = [];

   for(var i=0, l=this.length; i<l; i++){
      if(map[this[i]]){ continue; }

      out.push(this[i]);
      map[this[i]] = 1;
   }

   return out;
}
```

There's also no reason you can't use jQuery.unique.  The only thing I don't like about it is that it destroys the ordering of your array.  Here's the exact code for it if you're interested:

```
Sizzle.uniqueSort = function(results){
    if ( sortOrder ) {
        hasDuplicate = baseHasDuplicate;
        results.sort(sortOrder);

        if ( hasDuplicate ) {
            for ( var i = 1; i < results.length; i++ ) {
                if ( results[i] === results[i-1] ) {
                    results.splice(i--, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Paul Irish has a "[Duck Punching](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/)" method (see example 2) that modifies jQuery's `$.unique()` method to return unique elements of any type:

```
(function($){
    var _old = $.unique;
    $.unique = function(arr){
        // do the default behavior only if we got an array of elements
        if (!!arr[0].nodeType){
            return _old.apply(this,arguments);
        } else {
            // reduce the array to contain no dupes via grep/inArray
            return $.grep(arr,function(v,k){
                return $.inArray(v,arr) === k;
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6):

this is js1568's solution, modified to work on a **generic** array of objects, like:

```
 var genericObject=[
        {genProp:'this is a string',randomInt:10,isBoolean:false},
        {genProp:'this is another string',randomInt:20,isBoolean:false},
        {genProp:'this is a string',randomInt:10,isBoolean:true},
        {genProp:'this is another string',randomInt:30,isBoolean:false},
        {genProp:'this is a string',randomInt:40,isBoolean:true},
        {genProp:'i like strings',randomInt:60,isBoolean:true},
        {genProp:'this is a string',randomInt:70,isBoolean:true},
        {genProp:'this string is unique',randomInt:50,isBoolean:true},
        {genProp:'this is a string',randomInt:50,isBoolean:false},
        {genProp:'i like strings',randomInt:70,isBoolean:false}
    ]
```

It accepts one more parameter called propertyName, guess! :)

```
  $.extend({
        distinctObj:function(obj,propertyName) {
            var result = [];
            $.each(obj,function(i,v){
                var prop=eval("v."+propertyName);
                if ($.inArray(prop, result) == -1) result.push(prop);
            });
            return result;
        }
    });
```

so, if you need to extract a list of unique values for a given property, for example the values used for randomInt property, use this:

```
$.distinctObj(genericObject,'genProp');
```

it returns an array like this:

```
["this is a string", "this is another string", "i like strings", "this string is unique"]
```

Comment: I would really like to know what did I write to deserve a -1.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I just saw this answer), but I suggest you change `eval("v."+propertyName)` to `v[propertyName]`. Every time you call `eval` you start up another compiler. For a loop, this is pretty expensive.

Answer (score 5):

```
function array_unique(array) {
    var unique = [];
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i ) {
        if ( unique.indexOf(array[i]) == -1 )
            unique.push(array[i]);
    }
    return unique;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Plain JavaScript modern solution if you don't need IE support (`Array.from` is not supported in IE).

You can use combination of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
const set = new Set(arr);
const uniqueArr = Array.from(set);

console.log(uniqueArr);
```

The [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

The [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

Also `Array.from()` can be replaced with spread operator.

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
const set = new Set(arr);
const uniqueArr = [...set];

console.log(uniqueArr);
```

Comment: var arr = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
[... new Set(arr)];

Comment: @AshishSinghRawat Thank you, added option with spread operator syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a jQuery plugin called [Array Utilities](http://plugins.jquery.com/array-utilities/) to get an array of unique items.
It can be done like this:

```
var distinctArray = $.distinct([1, 2, 2, 3])
```

distinctArray = [1,2,3]

Comment: This union function also supports an arbitrary number of arrays, This package [jquery-array-utilities](https://libraries.io/bower/jquery-array-utilities) can also be installed using [bower](https://bower.io). I would like like to add a disclaimer that I originally made the plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) try:

```
ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues()
```

BTW have look at all `ko.utils.array*` utilities.

Answer (score 0):

As of jquery 3.0 you can use `$.uniqueSort(ARRAY)`

Example

```
array = ["1","2","1","2"]
$.uniqueSort(array)
=> ["1", "2"]
```

Comment: Actually, `uniqueSort` is the same as `unique` in jquery 2. It is intended to sort objects and not strings.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to support IE 8 or earlier, you can use jQuery to accomplish this.

```
var a = [1,2,2,3,4,3,5];
var unique = $.grep(a, function (item, index) {
   return index === $.inArray(item, a);
});
```