# How to use $.unique() function

Tags: jquery

Please, help me to understand, how to use `$.unique()` function.

From the docs:

> Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed.

I'm trying this code:

```
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>

alert( $.unique($('.foo')).length );
```

It returns 3, but I supposed 1. What am I missing? And it would be great to see some practice example of using this function. Thanks.

P.S.

I've also tried to sort a few numbers, but got a very curious result.
The following code returns different values in different browsers!

`$.unique([ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1 ])`

- Safari - 1, 2, 3, 1
- Opera - 2, 1, 3
- FF - 3, 2, 1, 3
- Chrome - 3, 2, 1
- IE - 2, 1, 3

Comment: If you do $.unique($.unique([1,2,2,3,3,1])); in Chrome, you get [1,2,3].  Just saying.

Comment: @Ivan: Don't rely on that behavior.

Comment: @Rocket: As I said: "just saying."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$.unique` is only meant for arrays of DOM elements.  Not arrays of other things.

In your case, you have 3 `<h3>`s.  They are not the same DOM element, so `$.unique` doesn't remove them.

```
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>

alert($.unique($('.foo')).length);  // 3
```

`$.unique` is for arrays that may contain the same element multiple times.

```
<h1 class="foo otherFoo">Headline</h1>
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>

var $foo = $('.foo').get();
var $otherFoo = $('.otherFoo').get();

var $e = $foo.concat($otherFoo);
alert($e.length); // 3
alert($.unique($e).length); // 2
```

On another note, if you want to make `$.unique` sort arrays of other things, and not just DOMElements, you can do something like this (Taken from [here](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/)):

```
(function($){
    var _old = $.unique;
    $.unique = function(arr){
        // do the default behavior only if we got an array of elements
        if (!!arr[0].nodeType){
            return _old.apply(this,arguments);
        }
        else {
            // reduce the array to contain no dupes via grep/inArray
            return $.grep(arr,function(v,k){
                return $.inArray(v,arr) === k;
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `$('.foo').add('.otherFoo')` isn't an array, and doesn't contain any duplicates.

Comment: In other words, `$.unique()` removes *duplicate* DOM elements, but not *identical* DOM elements.

Comment: PaulPRO is right: `$('.foo')` is an array-like jQuery object, not an actual array. However, that fact is secondary in this case.

Comment: It's not secondary. `.add()` internally calls `$.unique` so your second example will output 2 whether you call `.unique` or not. (IE. `alert($('.foo').add('.otherFoo').length);` outputs 2. Try it.

Comment: I'm don't think it's possible in any context for a jQuery object to contain duplicates, so calling `.unique` on a jQuery object does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @PaulPRO: You're right.  Guess I need a better example of `$.unique`.  I'm trying to find a case where you can use `$.unique`.

Comment: @Rocket yup, oh well it's an easy mistake to make since `.unique` is such an obscure jQuery function, I'm guessing you've never used it before this example haha, I know I haven't. Not downvote worthy. Probably upvote worthy if you can edit it to include a different example :)

Comment: @PaulPRO: I just didn't realize `$.unique` only worked on arrays of DOMElements, not jQuery objects.

Comment: Nice answer. And could you explain, please, what is the difference between $('.foo') and $('.foo').get() ? Because I usually count array length by the former one.

Comment: @Webars: `$('.foo')` is a jQuery "array-like" object.  It has special properties.  `.get()` converts a jQuery object into a normal array of DOMElements.

Answer (score 4):

`$.unique` works on an array of DOMElements, not numbers, strings, or a even a jQuery object.

It is used internally by jQuery in `add()` to prevent duplicates from being added to the same jQuery object. Here is an example of it:

HTML:

```
<h1 class="foo">Headline</h1>
<h1 class="foo bar">Headline</h1>
<h1 class="bar">Headline</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
var foo = $('.foo').get(); // Array of size 2
var bar = $('.bar').get(); // Array of size 2
var myArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
    myArr.push(foo[i]);
for(i = 0; i < bar.length; i++)
    myArr.push(bar[i]);

alert(myArr.length); // Outputs 4
alert($.unique(myArr).length); // Outputs 3
```

It should be very rare that you have an ordinary Javascript array of DOMElements though, if you're using jQuery. It is most useful internally within the jQuery source code.

PS. If you want to remove duplicate entries from an array of numbers/strings I recommend using js158's jQuery solution in this question: [jQuery function to get all unique elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381621/jquery-function-to-get-all-unique-elements-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/):

> Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

So that's why the numbers are different.

The function only removes duplicate DOM elements, not their `innerHTML` values in case that's what you were wondering, there's examples how to use it over on the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

> Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

It also provides an example.

Answer (score -3):

```
$.unique(array)
```

unique is an inbuilt jQuery function to return unique values from an
   Jaascript array.