# Using split function to output distinct values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array:

```
var fruits = ["orange","orange,apple","apple,orange,pear"];
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
fruits = ["orange","apple","pear"]
```

Any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11247412/1823841

Comment: Give Underscore a try; http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Comment: You want to break the original array of strings into an array of words with duplicates removed?

Comment: http://31.222.187.42/hca-consulting/mobile/

Comment: By searching on a name all the records come in via JSON then a Refined search on the returned data brings in the NHS hospitals of the records into the dropdown NHS Hospital, but there are values with commas. I am trying to pull disinct value by using the following function:

Comment: http://31.222.187.42/hca-consulting/mobile/hca.txt

Comment: By clicking on search by name all JSON is returned then a Refined search on the returned data brings in the NHS hospitals from the JSON records into the dropdown NHS Hospital, but there are values with commas in the dropdown. I am trying to pull disinct values into the dropdown by using the following function:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no readymade way to achieve this.

What you could do is use associative arrays that act like dictionaries. Iterate through the list, read each element, split it and store it in an associative array with the key as the fruit name, and the value as the fruit name too. Something like:

```
fruits["orange"] = "orange";
```

If the value already exists in fruits[], it will simply be overwritten. At the end,  you'll have as many keys in fruits[] as there are unique fruits.

EDIT:

```
var fruits = ["orange", "orange,apple", "apple,orange,pear"];
var a = fruits.toString().split(",");
var obj = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    obj[a[i]] = a[i];
}
for (var key in obj) {
  alert(key);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it:

```
fruits = fruits.reduce(function (p, c) {
    return p.concat(c.split(","));
}, []).filter(function(e, i, a) {
    return a.indexOf(e) === i;
});
```

(EDIT: Note that [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) are not supported in IE8 or older, but there are shims available if you need to support older IE.)

Comment: Deleting my answer out of sheer embarrassment compared to this. +1

Comment: Ha, thanks @RGraham. This _is_ nice and short, but not necessarily efficient using `.indexOf()` inside the `.filter()` callback like that. Still, it's the first idea that came to mind and like I said, it's _one_ way to do it.

Comment: I don't think there are enough fruits on the planet for it to make a difference anyway :)

Comment: Please see this link as this is my problem - http://31.222.187.42/hca-consulting/mobile/hca.txt

Comment: @CoolDude - Why do we need to follow a link to see your problem? You've explained the problem in your question, and several people have provided answers that will produce the output you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Will give you the expected result.

```
var fruits = ["orange","orange,apple","apple,orange,pear"];
var uniqueVal = [];
$.each(fruits, function(i, el){
    var splitVals = el.split(',');
    for(var i=0; i<splitVals.length; i++ ){
        if($.inArray(splitVals[i], uniqueVal) === -1) uniqueVal.push(splitVals[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var fruits = ["orange","orange,apple","apple,orange,pear"];
```

if you want to split the 2nd elements and concat the strings

```
fruits.concat(fruits[1].split(","))
```

or you want all the elements split and concat then uniq

```
  var new_fruits = [];
  $.each(fruits, function(i, el){
    fruits.concat(fruits[i].split(","))
    if($.inArray(el, new_fruits) === -1) new_fruits.push(el);

  });
```

or using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

```
 _.uniq(fruits, false)
```

Comment: What happened to splitting the input strings up?

Comment: you means you want only last element of that array after split?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but the question indicates that the second array element `"orange,apple"` should be split up into `"orange"` and `"apple"`, and similar for the third array element. Then after that only the unique strings should be kept.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var fruits = ["orange","orange,apple","apple,orange,pear"];
var out = [];

$(fruits).each(function(i) {
 var s = fruits[i].split(',');  
   $(s).each(function(i) {
    if($.inArray(s[i], out)===-1) 
       {
           out.push(s[i]);
       }
   });
});
```

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rRC65/

Answer (score 0):

This uses an object to capture the elements, then return its keys. And no need for shims.

```
function remdupes(arr) {
  var obj = {}, out = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = arr[i].split(',');
    for (var ii = 0, ll = el.length; ii < ll; ii++) {
      obj[el[i]] = true;
    }
  }
  for (var key in obj) { out.push(key); }
  return out;
}
```

Note that the last couple of lines:

```
for (var key in obj) { out.push(key); };
return out
```

can be rewritten:

```
return Object.keys(obj);
```

Comment: http://31.222.187.42/hca-consulting/mobile/hca.txt is some extra information regarding my problem

Comment: @CoolDude - did you mean to add this to another post?

Comment: No its related I just tried to simplify the problem and seem to have described a JSON object as a Javscript array so I dont have a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

You could do this like so ([eliminateDuplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840849/1636522)) :

```
fruits = fruits.join(','); // "orange,orange,apple,apple,orange,pear"
fruits = fruits.split(','); // ["orange", "orange", "apple", "apple", "orange", "pear"]
fruits = eliminateDuplicates(fruits); // ["orange", "apple", "pear"]
```