# How Can I retrieve the number of identical values in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

`var array = ['box','box','line','time','box']`

for Example : box is repeated several times

Comment: Loop, compare, count ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-a-array

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/507855/Get-Unique-Values-from-a-JavaScript-Array

Comment: The number of unique values with duplicates? The number of times a certain value exists? Or the total number of duplicate values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    var array = ['box','box','line','time','box'],
    map = {},
    key;

array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (map[item] === undefined) {
        map[item] = 1;
    } else {
        map[item]++;
    }
});

for (key in map) {
    console.log(" key:", key, " repeated:", map[key]);
}
```

Comment: `item in map` would be better than `=== undefined`.