# Javascript : String split() Method only push unique char

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I think the title is self explanatory. Is it possible to only push the unique char from a string into the array using split() methode?
Example : 
from string "javascript", I want an output array to be :

```
["j", "a", "v", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "t"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What unique char? I'm afraid I don't understand

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get unique values in a array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-a-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
'javascript'.split('').filter(function(value, index, self) { 
   return self.indexOf(value) === index;
 })
```

Comment: No, it will produce an array like this :
["j", "a", "v", "a", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "t"]
I only want need one "a".

Comment: @catwoman:  This one works well. Result is: ["j", "a", "v", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "t"]

Answer (score 2):

'javascript'.split('') => ['j', 'a', 'v', 'a', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't']

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var string = 'javascript';
var uniqueArr = [];
string.split('').forEach(function(e, i) {
    if (uniqueArr.indexOf(e) == -1) {
        uniqueArr.push(e)
    }
});
```

`uniqueArr` would contain all your 'unique char's

Comment: Note that `indexOf` on arrays first was implemented in IE9

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash array to remember chars have appeared.

```
function unqArr(str) {

    //char flag hash
    var unqHash = {};

    return str.split('').filter(function(c) {

        //this char has appeared
        if (unqHash[c])
            return false;

        //flag this char
        unqHash[c] = 1;
        return true;
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/s92Jm/