# Fastest way to get count of unique elements in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I need to find the number of unique elements in an array.

```
var myArray = [ 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60 ];
```

I want `count = 6` (number of unique elements in array)

And, is there a way to do this without iterating through the array? (I assume that would be the fastest way?).

ANSWER:   I used the .filter method as shown below.  My actual array element is much more complex.  I ended up iterating through my array and created a new array.  Each element in the new array was a .substr  of the old element.  Then, the .filter method below worked great.  THANKS to everyone!!

Comment: I think you can get help from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-a-array

Comment: Yep.  Looked at that.  But that's different.  I only want one number.

Comment: Use underscore.js `_.uniq(myArray).length`.

Comment: You can create a object

Comment: do you mean pull in the library underscore?

Comment: No, there's definitely no way to do this without iteration the array.

Comment: @finishingmove: That might be the shortest way, but probably not the fastest :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to keep a set of known values, and an auxilliary count.  You can use `.reduce()`:

```
var count = myArray.reduce(function(values, v) {
  if (!values.set[v]) {
    values.set[v] = 1;
    values.count++;
  }
  return values;
}, { set: {}, count: 0 }).count;
```

Starting with an empty set of values and a count of zero, this looks at each element to see whether it's been added to the set. If it hasn't, it's added, and the count is incremented.

Comment: so, in this case it returns count = 6 ?   Is it the fastest way?

Comment: I set up a performance test between your method of reducing vs a vanilla *Object set*: http://jsperf.com/js-set-test

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl For me the "reduce" is faster, but I suspect a big part of that is that the "simple" code is (correctly!) making a `hasOwnProperty` test. Otherwise the two approaches are almost exactly the same, if implemented slightly differently.

Answer (score 14):

ES6 offers a single line solution:

```js
new Set(myArray).size
```

Comment: `myArray` can also be a string. A fantastic use of ES6.

Answer (score 3):

How about `filter` and length:

```
var len = myArray.filter(function(val, i, arr) { 
    return arr.indexOf(val) === i;
}).length;
```

Comment: hmmmm.  so. what variable?  is equal to 6 here?

Comment: I'm favoring your method for the simple reason that it necessitates less code.  Two questions though.  1.  is it as fast as the above two methods?  and 2.  I need some help understanding what (val, i, arr) mean.  So, in my case, I need to find the "count" of a substring of an element in the array.  So in this case  for example, I need to find the number of unique occurrances of myArray.substr(3,6).  I'm not sure how this maps to (val, i, arr)...   thanks!

Comment: @hypermiler https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @hypermiler this is simpler, but for long arrays it's going to be expensive. The `.indexOf` operation has to perform a linear search, so the execution time tends to be proportional to the *square* of the length of the array (particularly when there are not many duplicates).

Comment: this is a very short array.  Maybe max 30 elements. Usually much less.  And the likelihood of duplicates is low.

Comment: @David.  I really feel bad, this is way above my head.  Sorry.  I went to mozilla.  Still can't get it.  I tried to ask another question and was roundly chastised.  Deleted the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using lodash:

```
_.uniq(myArray).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now convert your array into a **unique Array** and compare lengths.
Do this by changing it into **Set** and then back to an **Array**. If the **Set** is smaller then duplicates were removed and your original Array did not contain unique values.

`const isUnique = (myArray.length === [...new Set(myArray)].length);`

test:

```
const myArray=[1,2,2,3,4]; 
console.log(myArray.length === [...new Set(myArray)].length);
false

const myArray=[1,2,3,4]; 
console.log(myArray.length === [...new Set(myArray)].length);
true
```