# Extract Keywords from String: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

Lets consider i have a string & want to extract uncommon keywords for SEO. `$text = "This is some text. This is some text. Vending Machines are great.";`

& Will define a array of common words to ignore keywords in extracted list like `$commonWords = ['i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www'];`

Expected output: `Result=[some,text,machines,vending]`

Would really appreciate if Could any one help us to write generic logic or procedure for the extracting keywords from string?

Comment: remove punctuation marks ([`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)), split the string ([`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)), filter the array for words not found in the `$commonWords` array ([`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some like this

```
var $commonWords = ['i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www'];
var $text = "This is some text. This is some text. Vending Machines are great.";

// Convert to lowercase
$text = $text.toLowerCase();

// replace unnesessary chars. leave only chars, numbers and space
$text = $text.replace(/[^\w\d ]/g, '');

var result = $text.split(' ');

// remove $commonWords
result = result.filter(function (word) {
    return $commonWords.indexOf(word) === -1;
});

// Unique words
result = result.unique();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: There is nothing like `Array.prototype.unique` in the standard

Comment: @Andreas You have right. Here is solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array or better: http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Comment: @Andreas:How to handle if string contains special characters?

Comment: @Niks Such as? And this should probably be an update to your question instead of a comment on one of the possible solutions.

Comment: `s.replace(/[^\w\d ]/g, '')` leaves only chars, numbers and space. I update the solution

Answer (score 5):

This can help ( it supports multi languages):

https://github.com/michaeldelorenzo/keyword-extractor

```
var sentence = "President Obama woke up Monday facing a Congressional defeat that many in both parties believed could hobble his presidency."

//  Extract the keywords
var extraction_result = keyword_extractor.extract(sentence,{
                                                            language:"english",
                                                            remove_digits: true,
                                                            return_changed_case:true,
                                                            remove_duplicates: false

                                                       });
```

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "This is some text. This is some text. Vending Machines are great.";

var substrings = ['your','words', 'here'],

var results = array();
for (var i = substrings.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (string.indexOf(substrings[i]) != -1) {
         // str contains substrings[i]
         array.push(substrings[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayLength = commonWords.length;
var words = [];   //new array to say the words
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if ($text.indexOf(commonWords[i]) > -1){
        words.push(commonWords[i]);
    }
}
```