# What is the best way to get paired data of this array model?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am kind of new in programming world, please help me. Any help would be appreciated! 
I have an array with data like shown below. I have to make the data so that in every group only contains paired `user_id` in sequence. The paired `user_id` should be different if they are going to be paired.

```
  [
      {"user_id": 35, "group": "A"},
      {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
      {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
      {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
      {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
      {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
      {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
      {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
      {"user_id": 40, "group": "C"},
      {"user_id": 39, "group": "C"}
    ]
```

So the data will be like this:

The first item is removed because it doesn't has pair.
The 5th and 6th items are removed because it has same user_ids with each other (`user_id` should be different if it is going to be paired).

```
[
  {"user_id": 35, "group": "A"}, <-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"}, <-- remove
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"}, <-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"}, <-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"}, <-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "C"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "C"}
]
```

So, the result would be:

```
[
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "C"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "C"}
]
```

What is the best way to achieve this (using splice method or create a new array and then push it, or another ways)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for(var i = 0; arr.length > i;) {
  if (!arr[i+1] || arr[i].group != arr[i+1].group) {
    //arr[i] is last in the group
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else if (arr[i].user_id == arr[i+1].user_id || (arr[i-1] && arr[i].user_id == arr[i-1].user_id && arr[i].group == arr[i-1].group)) {
    //next or previous item have same id and group
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    //arr[i] and arr[i+1] is a valid pair
    i += 2;
  }
}
```

```js
var arr = [
  {"user_id": 35, "group": "A"}, //<-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"}, //<-- remove
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"}, //<-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"}, //<-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"}, //<-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "C"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "C"}
]

for(var i = 0; arr.length > i;) {
  if (!arr[i+1] || arr[i].group != arr[i+1].group) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else if (arr[i].user_id == arr[i+1].user_id || (arr[i-1] && arr[i].user_id == arr[i-1].user_id && arr[i].group == arr[i-1].group)) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    i += 2;
  }
}

arr.forEach(function(e) {
  document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(e) + "<br>";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on `filter` and `reduce`:

```js
var input = [{"user_id": 35, "group": "A"},
             {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
             {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
             {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
             {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
             {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
             {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
             {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
             {"user_id": 40, "group": "C"},
             {"user_id": 39, "group": "C"}];

var output = input.filter(function(el, idx, input) {
  // filter unique records
  next = input[idx+1];
  return !next || el.group !== next.group || el.user_id !== next.user_id;
}).reduce(function(prev, el, idx, input) {
  // match pairs if in same group
  next = input[idx+1];
  return (prev.length%2 || next && el.group === next.group)
         ? prev.concat([el]) : prev;
}, []);

// output
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output).replace(/\},/g, '}<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach given at [How to get unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array) to get only the distinct values in the array, then just remove the values that don't have any pairs

```
[
  {"user_id": 35, "group": "A"}, <-- remove
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "B"},
  {"user_id": 40, "group": "C"},
  {"user_id": 39, "group": "C"}
]
```