# Converting duplicate items in array into unique items without removing any item in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array with list of items.Some items are duplicates.I need the way to make those items as unique.I know of using track by $index in ng-repeat of angularjs.But i want to use the array without trackby.as a regular ng-repeat.

```
Array=[
        { name:'john',salary:'2000'},{ name:'john',salary:'2000'},{ name:'john',salary:'2000'},{ name:'harry',salary:'2000'}]
```

Is there any way I can do it in controller of the angularjs.I tried adding new field to the array Like this:

```
for(x in Array){
 Array[x].unique=x;
  }
```

But it givessame value to all the duplicate items.
Any way to resolve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Try to use other variable name other than Array

Comment: isn't clear what you mean with `using track by`, that's doesn't solve your problem and, just for being clear, `track by` is awseome for performances improvements...

Comment: There are symbols in JS to assign  unique identities to objects. More for symbols please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: @PranavCBalan I just used Array to say its Array data.

Comment: @MysterX The link you provided is to avoid the duplicates. I need all the items to be listed.

Comment: @Hitmands Yes I can display all the items in ng-repeat with track by. But i only wanted to know  why binding an extra field in the controller using for each don't works.

Comment: Is it accurate to say, then, that you just want to give each item a unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash's _.uniq()

```
newArr = _.uniq(arr);
```