# Look through every items in array(A) and check if it allready exsists in another array(B)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have two arrays(arrayA & arrayB). I want to check if any of the items in arrayA allready exists in arrayB. if it doesn't I want to add it to arrayB(but that's not the problem). In the exampel I just want to console.log that I'm adding the item to array B.

First I thought this was a good idea:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
            if(body[i].id == res[j].name){
                console.log("The article allready exsists")
            }
            else{
                console.log("Adding item to arrayB")
            }


      }

      }
```

Then I realised that this wasn't a verry good way to do it because the array's are pretty big. Also the else-statement will be ran the number of times equal to the length of arrayA. Also It's a problem because the first time this will run the array length of arrayB will be zero and wont even reach the else-statement.

Is their any other ways to achive what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: you can store (push) the missing values in another array(C), then concat it to array B after the for loops are done

Comment: So if I understand right, you want to push unique items in `ArrayB`. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @Rajesh, please explain your downvote.

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Not my vote. I comment when I downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this could help. You donot need nested loops for achieving this.

```
 var arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 var arrayB = [2,4,7,8];
 for(var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
       if(arrayB.indexOf(arrayA[i]) > -1){
            console.log("The article allready exsists");
         }
         else{
             console.log("Adding item to arrayB")
         }
   }
```

Comment: Doesn't using indexOf count as a nested loop?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a hash table and a linear approach by iterating first `arrayB` and collect the `name` property and then iterate over `arrayA` and check if the `id` is in `arrayB` with the hash table. Add the information to `arrayB` if not exist.

```js
var arrayA = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 9 }, { id: 12 }, { id: 35 }, { id: 22 }, { id: 11 }, { id: 34 }, { id: 90 }, { id: 2 }],
    arrayB = [{ name: 1 }, { name: 7 }, { name: 8 }, { name: 19 }, { name: 25 }, { name: 41 }, { name: 35 }, ],
    hashB = Object.create(null);

arrayB.forEach(function (b) {
    hashB[b.name] = true;
});

arrayA.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!hashB[a.id]) {
        arrayB.push({ name: a.id });
        hashB[a.id] = true;
    }
});

console.log(arrayB);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Kinda over my level, not familiar with hash tables but will definitively look into it!