# I want to push an Object or an Array of Objects to an existed Array，and keep elements in the Array unique

Tags: javascript, arrays

when it's an Object i can use this method to get what i want

```
var obj=  {value: 'mouseup', label: 'mouseup'};

    var array = [
        {value: 'mouseup', label: 'mouseup'},
        {value: 'mousedown', label: 'mousedown'},
        {value: 'mousemove', label: 'mousemove'},
        {value: 'mouseover', label: 'mouseover'},
        {value: 'mouseout', label: 'mouseout'}
    ]

   function pushUnique(obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].value === obj.value) { 
            return array;
            }
        }
        array.push(obj);
        return array
   }
```

Are there any methods to do this? What if it's an Array of Objects below(e.g obj1),how can i push an Array of Objects(e.g obj1) to an existed Array(e.g array)，and keep elements in the Array(array) unique ?

```
obj1=  [
        {value: 'hover', label: 'hover'},
        {value: 'click', label: 'click'},
        {value: 'mouseup', label: 'mouseup'},
        {value: 'mousedown', label: 'mousedown'},
        {value: 'mousemove', label: 'mousemove'},
   ]

array = [
        {value: 'mouseup', label: 'mouseup'},
        {value: 'mousedown', label: 'mousedown'},
        {value: 'mousemove', label: 'mousemove'},
        {value: 'mouseover', label: 'mouseover'},
        {value: 'mouseout', label: 'mouseout'}
    ]
```

Comment: Just apply `pushUnique` to each element of `obj1`.

Comment: it looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/43134871/1447675

Comment: duplicate? similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Answer (score 0):

Check out [lodash.unionBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unionBy)

Here is an example:

> ```
> // The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
> _.unionBy([{ 'x': 1 }], [{ 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
> // => [{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }]
> ```