# how to restrict duplicate values from dropdown in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Here i have mentioned current image form.
[image]

1) It is an multiple select dropdown. it should restrict duplicate tax name.
for an example in this image two time that **CGST** selected.

while selecting same name it should show not display here.
so please help me to do this.

**html**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tax">Tax Name</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="tax_name" (change)=" dropdown(tax.value)" [(ngModel)]="model.tax" name="tax_name" #tax="ngModel">
    <option value="addNew">
      <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add New Tax </option>
    <hr>
    <br/>
    <option *ngFor="let i of taxlist" [value]="i.tax_name">{{i.tax_name}} &nbsp; ( {{i.tax_percentage}}% )</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>

  <label for="percentage">Tax Percentage</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tax_percentage" placeholder="Percentage" pattern="[0-9]+" minlength="0" maxlength="3"
    [(ngModel)]="per" name="tax_percentage" #percentage="ngModel">
</div>
<button (click)="addContact(tax.value,percentage.value);" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-right">
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: I think there is similar answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512528/how-go-get-ngfor-loop-unique-records

Comment: Actually im new to Angular  Could u please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. When you use *ngFor to loop over values you must remove any duplicate entries that are in the list. So, good way is to create a filter in Angular 2+ it is called a Pipe. It is basically filter that will remove your duplicate entries in the list so user won't be able to select multiple same values because they are filtered and not present in a list.

> ```
> @Pipe(name: 'unique') 
>   export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform
> {
>
>   transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
>
>     // Remove the duplicate elements (this will remove duplicates
>     let uniqueArray = value.filter(function (el, index, array) { 
>       return array.indexOf (el) == index;
>     });
>
>   return uniqueArray;   }
> ```
>
> }

And you will use this pipe in html :

```
 <option *ngFor="let i of taxlist | unique" [value]="i.tax_name {{i.tax_name}} &nbsp; ( {{i.tax_percentage}}% )</option>
```

But please import this Pipe and register it in module you are using it in.

Courtesy to link I've previously provided in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to Pipes OR you can use the newly introduced ES6 function

```
var items = [1,1,1,1,3,4,5,2,23,1,4,4,4,2,2,2]
var uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(items))
```

It will return the unique result.

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 23]
```