# Removing duplicate values from json array inside a dropdown?

Tags: angular

I m trying to display data from array inside a dropdown using ngFor. But i am getting duplicate values.How do i remove it?

Here is the entire data:
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Here is the currencies array  that i am trying to loop..

[image]

I m trying to display unique values based on name field of currency array.

Here is the GitHub link to the code:

https://github.com/saisreereddy/RestfulCountriesv3

The logic is inside the region component.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512528/how-go-get-ngfor-loop-unique-records?

Comment: does the data currencies may have same names?

Comment: yes they have same names in some arrays

Comment: @prachi...I have seen it and also tried but not working

Comment: What you want to do is create a custom pipe to filter out duplicate data. There are a number of SO posts on this. @Prachi listed one. Here are some more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362047/how-to-display-only-unique-values-in-the-dropdown-using-angular-2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417250/filtering-an-array-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable making a custom pipe, this can be done easily programatically, run this function on your currency array:

```
filterData(yourCurrencyData: any[]): any[] {
  const filteredArray = [];
  for (const currency of yourCurrencyData) {
    if(!filteredArray.find(c => c.code === currency.code) {
      filteredArray.push(currency);
    }
  }
  return filteredArray;
}
```

This will return your filtered array. Not terribly efficient, and a map would have faster look ups, but since there are a small number of currencies this is not an issue as this is very readable and the difference would not be noticeable by humans with only a few hundred records. Feel free to replace any with a Data Type. And remember to `*ngFor` over the new filtered array.