# Get number of each item in an array using a map

Tags: javascript, foreach, hashmap

I am trying to get the number of times each string item occurs in an array and print it out using a Map. I am basically reading in the data from firebase functions, but for now, I am using an array to test the code to get the occurrences of each item. I tried the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149482/count-occurrences-of-each-number-present-in-array-using-javascript), but it does not work and I am not sure why:

```
<script>
var appVersion= ["5012", "5021", "5012", "5011", "5012", "5021"];

var count = new Map();

appVersion.forEach(version=> count.set(count.get(version) + 1));

function show(versions) {
         document.write(versions);
         document.write("<br>");
      }
    count.forEach(show);
</script>
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you want to this

as discussed in the comments if you want the final object to be in this format :`{ '5011': 1, '5012': 3, '5021': 2 }`
you could use reduce

```js
var appVersion= ["5012", "5021", "5012", "5011", "5012", "5021"];


map=new Map
appVersion.forEach(o=>{
   count=map.get(o)||0
    map.set(o,count+1)
})
r=[...map].reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  if (acc.length==0) {acc.push({[curr[0]]:curr[1]})}
  else  {acc[0][curr[0]]=curr[1]}
 return acc
},[])

console.log(r)
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much. This helps a lot.

Comment: If I need to print the values without it seeming like a Json string, how would I approach that? Something like this: "5012: 3"

Comment: what do you mean ? do you want it to be represented like a string ? can you give me an example

Comment: Yes, Just plainly represented as a string.
`5012: 3` 
`5021: 2`

Comment: do you want them in an array ?

Comment: something like this: {
  "5011": 1,
  "5012": 3,
  "5021": 2
}

Comment: You could use reduce to loop through each element in the map and then add them to one object

Comment: I have updated my answer and now you will get the result in that format let me know if that's what you want

Comment: Yes, that is perfect, thank you so much for your time and effort, that really helped me.

Comment: Just one final thing, what does `acc` refer to?

Comment: that's  the `accumulator ` , curr is for `current `

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps

```js
var appVersion= ["5012", "5021", "5012", "5011", "5012", "5021"];

let counter = {}
for (version of appVersion){
    counter[version] = 1 + (counter[version] || 0)
}

console.log(counter);
```

Comment: This does help, but I strictly need to use a map for my case unfortunately. Any advice on that end would be really helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Using map:

```js
let contador = {};
appVersion.map(x => contador[x] = 1 + (contador[x] || 0));
console.log(contador);
```

Answer (score 0):

See below

```js
var appVersion= ["5012", "5021", "5012", "5011", "5012", "5021"];

var count = new Map();

appVersion.map( (version) => count.get( version) != undefined ? count.set( version, count.get( version) + 1 ) : count.set( version, 1 ) );

console.log( [...count].sort() );
```

Comment: how would I represent the output as something like this: something like this: `{ "5011": 1, "5012": 3, "5021": 2 }`

Comment: I see, but the output is still in this format: [
  `[
    "5011",
    1
  ],
  [
    "5012",
    3
  ],
  [
    "5021",
    2
  ]
]`


Whereas I am looking for something like this:
`{ "5011": 1, "5012": 3, "5021": 2 }`

Sorry for the bad format, comments don't allow me to format it properly

Comment: I apologise for the trouble, I tried it myself, but I am getting stuck with the format