# Remove Duplicate elements from Array - Javascript (No JQuery & ECMAScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Case: We have 'n' number of arrays stored in an array (Array of Arrays). Now that each child array in this parent array can have elements that may or may not be present in other child arrays. Output - I need to create an array which has the all the elements present in all the child arrays excluding the duplicates.

I do not want to concatenate all the arrays into a single array and use unique method to filter out. I need to create unique array then and there during iteration.

Ex:

```
var a[] = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b[] = [1,2,7,8];
var c[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var d[] = [9,10,11,12];
var arr[] = [a,b,c,d]
Output must be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

P.S: I can concat the arrays and use jquery unique function to resolve this, but i need a solution in javascript alone. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to use ES6?

Comment: Nope, just plain JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Thats not js ...

Comment: ES6 is plain javascript as well, just on different specification.

Comment: @Roomy. Have updated the question. Please check
I do not want to concatenate all the arrays into a single array and use unique method to filter out. I need to create unique array then and there during iteration. (No Jquery too)

Comment: @Moah, I think it's not possible without creating additional array eg. `[].concat(a,b,c,d).filter(...).sort(...)`, but I would like to know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Roomy Yes its not possible without creating an additional array but i dont want to concatenate and then apply the filter/unique. spetrila's solution works well i just did a slight modification based on my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce` to flatten your array and then use `Set` to get distinct values and use `array#from` to get back array from `Set`.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [1,2,7,8];
var c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var d = [9,10,11,12];
var arr = [a,b,c,d]

var result = Array.from(new Set(arr.reduce((r,a) => r.concat(a))));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looks more readable and optimised, but Set isn't supported in IE 8,9,10. My project needs to be compatible with IE 8+ versions. Anyways thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: You can try adding polyfill for `array#reduce`, `Set` and `array#from`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using .filter when adding each array to the final one, filtering out the duplicates:

```
a.filter(function(item) {
    return !finalArray.contains(item));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer using `Sets`:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [1,2,7,8];
var c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var d = [9,10,11,12];

var concat = a.concat(b).concat(c).concat(d);
var union = new Set(concat);
//console.log(union);
```

ES6 Answer:

```
let a = new Set([1,2,3,4,5]);
let b = new Set([1,2,7,8]);
let c = new Set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
let d = new Set([9,10,11,12]);

let arr = new Set([...a,...b,...c,...d]);
//Result in arr.
```

Whats going on???

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set:

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.

So when we initialise `Sets` passing arrays to the constructor we basically ensure that there are no duplicate values.

Then in the last line, we concat all the `Sets` we initialised prior into a final set.

The `...` notation converts the `Set` into an `array`, and when we pass the 4 arrays to the constructor of the `Set` they get concatenated and a `Set` of their unique values is created.

Comment: Please update your answer with an explanation of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional alternative written in ES5.

```
var flatten = function(list) {
  return list.reduce(function(acc, next) {
    return acc.concat(Array.isArray(next) ? flatten(next) : next);
  }, []);
};

var unique = function(list) {
  return list.filter(function(element, index) {
    return list.indexOf(element) === index;
  })
}


var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [1,2,7,8];
var c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var d = [9,10,11,12];
var arr = [a,b,c,d];

var result = unique(flatten(arr));

console.log(result);
```

If you support ES6, arrow function can make that code even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses a plain object for resolving duplicates, and only uses basic ES3 JavaScript. Runs in IE 5.5 and higher, and with *O(n)* time complexity.

```js
function uniques(arr) {
    var obj = {}, result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        obj[arr[i]] = true;
    }
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) result.push(+prop);
    }
    return result;
}

// Example use
var a = [1,2,3,4,5], 
    b = [1,2,7,8],
    c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    d = [9,10,11,12];

var result = uniques(a.concat(b, c, d));

console.log('Result: ' + result);
```

As an object can only have a unique set of properties (no duplicates), the use of all array values as properties in an object will give you an object with a property for each unique value. This happens in the first loop. NB: the value given to those properties is not relevant; I have used `true`.

Then the result is just the conversion of those properties back to array values. This happens in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [1,2,7,8];
var c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var d = [9,10,11,12];
var result = a.concat(b,c,d);
function remvDup(result){
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        if(tmp.indexOf(result[i]) == -1){
        tmp.push(result[i]);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
console.log(remvDup(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase the OP mentioned that he cannot use 'Set' as it is not supported on the targeted browsers, I would recommand using the `'union'` function from the lodash library.

[See union's documentation here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#union)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but my target was to achieve this without any library or external script, just plain JS.