# To get an array of distinct strings from a map, extracting the string from a property of the Map values

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, for-loop

I need to get an array of distinct strings from a map, extracting the string from a property of the Map's values. At the moment, I have the following code and was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it?

```
myMap   {   key1 : [{ a : “myA”, b : “myB”, c : “myC”}, {  a : “myAA”, b : “myB”, c : “myC”}],
            key2 : [{ a : “myAA”, b : “myB”, c : “myC”}, {  a : “myAAA”, b : “myB”, c : “myC”}]
        }
```

Ans needed = ["myA", "myAA", "myAAA"]

```
var ans = new Set();

for (let i of myMap.values()) {
    for (let j of i){
        ans.add(j.a);
    }
}

return Array.from(ans);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
 return [...new Set([...myMap.values()].map(el => el.a))];
```

Just use `map` to shortify it a bit.

---

Alternatively you could use a helper to ensure uniqueness:

```
const unique = (s = new Set) => el => !s.has(el) && s.add(el);
```

So you can just do:

```
return [...myMap.values()].filter(unique());
```

Comment: I'm afraid this gives me an undefined returned. I don't think it takes notice of the fact that each element of values is an array as well so there are more than one el in each.