# Axios VueJs Response Map Unique

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to retrieve car manufacturer ID's using **AXIOS** within **VueJs** front-end and **Spring** back-end. 
In the code provided below I have achieved that, however some of the ID's repeat(*this is meant to happen*), the question is how is it possible to filter out the duplicate ID's?

My `getMethod` below.

```
   getMethod () {
            AXIOS.get(`/url/`)

                .then(response => {
                        if (response.status == 200) {

this.response = response.data                                     
                            this.myTest = response.data.map(mesg => mesg.carManufacterId)
                            console.log(this.myTest)

                        }
                    },
                    (err) => {                

                       if (err.response.status == 500) {

                            console.log('turned off')
                        }
                        else if (err.response.status == 404) {                         
                                console.log('Could not retrieve)
                        }
                    })

        },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Similar but not a duplicate

Comment: Your question is "How to remove duplicates from array?", that's the same as "How to get unique values in an array?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve that by looping through your response data array and check in each iteration if the new item is already in `myTest` array based on `carManufacterId`:

```
this.myTest = []
response.data.forEach(item => {

  if (!this.myTest.some(rec => {
      return item.carManufacterId === rec.carManufacterId
    })) {
    this.myTest.push(item);
  }
});
```