# Sequelize CreateOrUpdate Function

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am using `node version v10.15.3` and `"sequelize": "^4.22.8"`. When using `bulkCreate` I am getting double values in my db:

My model looks like the following:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    url: DataTypes.STRING,
    symbol: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {})
  Company.associate = function(models) {
    Company.hasMany(models.Rating)
  };
  return Company
};
```

I have created a custom `createOrUpdateCompany()` function. Find below my minimum executable example:

```
const models = require('./src/models');
const Company = require('./src/models').Company;

async function getAllCompanies() {
    try {
        let res = await Company.findAll()
        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

async function createOrUpdateCompany(dataArray) {

    if (dataArray === undefined || dataArray.length === 0) return ''

    let iss = []

    const allCompanies = await getAllCompanies()

    // flatten array
    dataArray = [].concat.apply([], dataArray)

    if (allCompanies !== undefined) {
        // 1. remove exact dedupes from dataArray
        dataArray = [...new Map(dataArray.map(obj => [JSON.stringify(obj), obj])).values()]

        // 2. compare dataArray to allCompanies and remove difference
        // dataArray = dataArray.filter(cv => !allCompanies.find(e => e.symbol === cv.symbol))
        dataArray = dataArray.filter(cv => !allCompanies.find(e => e.symbol === cv.symbol))

        // 3. Remove null values for link and "" values for name
        dataArray = dataArray.filter(cv => !(cv.name === '' || cv.url === null))
    }

    try {
        iss = await Company.bulkCreate(dataArray, {
            fields: [
                'name',
                'url',
                'symbol',
                'description',
            ]
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    return iss
}

let data = [{
    "date": "9/14/2019",
    "issuer": "Issuer6",
    "name": "Name1",
    "symbol": "Symbol2",
    "url": "www.url.com"
}, {
    "date": "9/11/2029",
    "issuer": "Issuer3",
    "name": "Name1",
    "symbol": "Symbol1",
    "url": "www.url.com"
}, {
    "date": "8/13/2019",
    "issuer": "Issuer1",
    "name": "Name1",
    "symbol": "Symbol1",
    "url": "www.url.com"
}]

async function main() {
    // setup db
    await models.sequelize.sync({
        force: true
    })

    await createOrUpdateCompany(data)
    await createOrUpdateCompany(data)
    await createOrUpdateCompany(data)
    await createOrUpdateCompany(data)

    console.log("##################### DONE #####################");
}

main()
```

When executing the above example I get the following in my db:

[image]

However, I would like to get only the following as result:

[image]

As you can see I only get two entries based on the unique result.

Any suggestions why my `createOrUpdateCompany()` is wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Please check your array data

Comment: There are 2 different dates with the same symbol ( ` "symbol": "Symbol1" `)

Comment: @NeelRathod Thx for your reply! Yes I was thinking that the problem is coming from the array. However, why aren`t the duplicates not removed OR is there any easier way how to `bulkCreateAndUpdate()` data to the db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve uniqueness in your result

> 1. Filter your array data before execution (Javascript stuff)
>      [Unique elements from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)
> 2. Make specific fields unique in the DB (composite unique) (Database stuff)[Add Composite unique key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: Thx for your reply! How could I improve the above example?