# Remove duplication of Id?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why spread is not removing the duplication from the Items?

I am using spread to merge two variables `resultA` and `resultB`. There are two duplicated Id (222) in DataA and DataB which should be removed when using spread. Why it did not happen and how to solve this?

```js
const DataA = [
  { Id: 111, Name: 'A'  },
  { Id: 222, Name: 'B'  },
  { Id: 333, Name: 'C'  }
]

const DataB = [
  { Id: 999, Name: 'A'  },
  { Id: 222, Name: 'B'  },
  { Id: 444, Name: 'C'  }
]

let resultA = (DataA || []).map(item => item.Id);
let resultB = (DataB || []).map(item => item.Id);

const items = [
  ...resultA,
  ...resultB,
]

const mapping = {
  Total: items.length,
  Items: items.map(item => { return { Id: item }})
}

console.log(mapping);
```

Expected Result:

```
{ Total: 5,
  Items:
   [ { Id: 111 },
     { Id: 222 },
     { Id: 333 },
     { Id: 999 },
     { Id: 444 } ] 
}
```

Comment: Why would the spread syntax remove duplicates?

Comment: I thought it does, how would you rewrite this?

Comment: const items = [
  ...new Set(resultA),
  ...new Set(resultB),
]

Comment: All it does is unpack an array as individual elements. So if you need [a Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), as just mentioned: "use a Set" =)

Comment: Spread literally just spreads array values.  It doesn't de-dup. No idea where you got that idea from.

Comment: I'd use a Set to store the IDs, since then they'd be unique. Then map the Set to items afterwards as you do here. [Suggestions on how to do this (and other techiques) here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the same question about 15 minutes ago?

Comment: @zfrisch He's thinking of when you spread objects rather than arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The spread syntax on arrays doesn't remove duplicates. To get the result you wanted, Add a line 
`items = [...new Set(items)]` after items

```js
const DataA = [
  { Id: 111, Name: 'A'  },
  { Id: 222, Name: 'B'  },
  { Id: 333, Name: 'C'  }
]

const DataB = [
  { Id: 999, Name: 'A'  },
  { Id: 222, Name: 'B'  },
  { Id: 444, Name: 'C'  }
]

let resultA = (DataA || []).map(item => item.Id);
let resultB = (DataB || []).map(item => item.Id);

let items = [
  ...resultA,
  ...resultB,
]

items = [...new Set(items)] // this will remove duplicates 

const mapping = {
  Total: items.length,
  Items: items.map(item => { return { Id: item }})
}

console.log(mapping);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you've read that spread removes duplicates, but it does not. Luckily, there are a number of simple ways to achieve this - below is one option that involves very little modification to your code. Simply wrap the array containing items from the 2 spread arrays in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) constructor (since I see you're already coding to the ES6 spec).

**From MDN**:

> Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the
>   elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only
>   occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection.

Finally, you can simply wrap the `Set` in [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to get back to an array (among other ways to do this).

```js
const DataA = [{
    Id: 111,
    Name: 'A'
  },
  {
    Id: 222,
    Name: 'B'
  },
  {
    Id: 333,
    Name: 'C'
  }
]

const DataB = [{
    Id: 999,
    Name: 'A'
  },
  {
    Id: 222,
    Name: 'B'
  },
  {
    Id: 444,
    Name: 'C'
  }
]

let resultA = (DataA || []).map(item => item.Id);
let resultB = (DataB || []).map(item => item.Id);

const items = Array.from(new Set([
  ...resultA,
  ...resultB,
]));

const mapping = {
  Total: items.length,
  Items: items.map(item => {
    return {
      Id: item
    }
  })
}

console.log(mapping);
```