# How to get *index* of unique values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to get the *indexes* of unique values within an array. I've found several solutions to removing duplicate values of an array, for instance here:

[How to get unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

but am having trouble finding how to get back the indexes of those unique values vs. the values themselves.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log(fruits.indexOf("Apple") )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is there a way to detect that "Apple" is unique before getting its index?

Comment: you can use `array.includes()`