# Filter html elements based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="child_1" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_2" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_3" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_4" data-customId="20">
    </div>
    <div id="child_5" data-customId="323">
    </div>
    <div id="child_6" data-customId="14">
    </div>
</div>
```

And what I want to do is to get the count of child divs that contains different data attribute. For example, I'm trying this:

```
$(`div[id*="child_"]`).length); // => 6
```

But that code is returning 6 and what I want to retrieve is 4, based on the different data-customId. So my question is, how can I add a filter/map to that selector that I already have but taking into consideration that is a data-attribute.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
var divs = $(`div[id*="child_"]`);
var count = divs.map(div => div.data-customId).length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you getting the `child-divs` map their `customid` and just get the length of [`unique values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array):

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(`div[id*="child_"]`);
let idCustoms = [...divs].map(div=>div.dataset.customid);
//idCustoms: ["100", "100", "100", "20", "323", "14"]
//get unique values with Set 
console.log([... new Set(idCustoms)].length);//4
//or with filter
console.log(idCustoms.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i).length);//4
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="child_1" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_2" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_3" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_4" data-customId="20">
    </div>
    <div id="child_5" data-customId="323">
    </div>
    <div id="child_6" data-customId="14">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** `$` is equivalent  to `document.querySelectorAll` in `js` returns a *NodeList* that's why I destructure it by the three dots `...`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to extract the attribute value from each, then count up the number of uniques.

```js
const { size } = new Set(
  $('[data-customId]').map((_, elm) => elm.dataset.customid)
);
console.log(size);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="child_1" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_2" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_3" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_4" data-customId="20">
    </div>
    <div id="child_5" data-customId="323">
    </div>
    <div id="child_6" data-customId="14">
    </div>
</div>
```

No need for jQuery for something this trivial, though.

```js
const { size } = new Set(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-customId]')].map(elm => elm.dataset.customid)
);
console.log(size);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="child_1" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_2" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_3" data-customId="100">
    </div>
    <div id="child_4" data-customId="20">
    </div>
    <div id="child_5" data-customId="323">
    </div>
    <div id="child_6" data-customId="14">
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the property `customid` is lower-cased in the JavaScript. This could be an easy point of confusion. You might consider changing your HTML from

```
data-customId="14"
```

to

```
data-custom-id="14"
```

so that you can use `customId` in the JS (to follow the common conventions).