# sort an array of words(each word appears several times in the array), i want to make new array that all the words will appears only once

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, vuejs2

```
array = ['dog','dog','dog','cat','cat', 'mouse','egg','egg']
newArray = ['dog','cat','mouse','egg']: expected array.
```

thank you.

i tried to run with map and compre the word to the other words at differet index.

Comment: There's no sorting in here. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Seems you just want to remove duplicate element and keep the same order?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

Your second array isn't sorted but...

To sort the array use:
array.sort()

To get unique values:
Array.from(new Set(array))

Also do not name your array array.

This was already answered here:
[How to get unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: If it is already answered, please flag it as a duplicate instead of answering again