# Find all matches in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the regex to search for all instances of the string that matches **Hello[n]** pattern.

```
var str = 'Hello[0] hello[2] hell Welcome to JavaScript.';
var regex = /hello+/gi;
var result = str.match(regex);
```

The code above produces the following outcome.

```
[ 'Hello', 'hello' ]
```

I want to know how to modify my regex to produce the following result.

```
[ 'Hello[0]', 'hello[1]',..... ]
```

Comment: ```/hello\[\d+\]/gi```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the number, you've to change the Regex to `hello\[\d+\]+`.
Working example: https://regex101.com/r/Xtt6ds/1

So you get:

```js
var str = 'Hello[0] hello[2] hell Welcome to JavaScript.';
var regex = /hello\[\d+\]+/gi;
var result = str.match(regex);
```

Comment: thnx it worked. What if `Hello[0] hello[2] hell Welcome hello[2]`  i want to get the unique occurrence of `hello[2]` ?

Comment: @Nabeel easiest way would be to add some JavaScript magic, like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/3653544 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/42123984/3653544

Answer (score 1):

Extend your current regex pattern to include the square brackets:

```js
var str = 'Hello[0] hello[2] hell Welcome to JavaScript.';
var matches = str.match(/hello\[.*?\]/gi);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = 'Hello[0] hello[2] hell Welcome to JavaScript.';
var regex = /Hello\[[0-9]+\]+/gi ;
var result = str.match(regex)
console.log(result)
```