# Hide if html is the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, if-statement

I'm using Feedburner to show feeds. sometimes the feeds have the same title. In situations where this is the case I would like to show only the first title and hide all the other titles with the same text. I tried this: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHEKd/1/)

No luck. I can refer to them as 'a' but I don't understand how to distinguish them from one another.

Comment: It doesnt show anything in the output

Comment: That't because I have display:none .....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381621/jquery-function-to-get-all-unique-elements-from-an-array

Should help you figure out how to filter unique elements from array of results.

Comment: @goldenparrot Thanks +1, I have tried it at http://jsfiddle.net/NHEKd/2/ I can't seem to 'show' the var unique...maybe you can help me out (answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with all links showing and this javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var $feeds = $(".feedburnerFeedBlock li a");
    $feeds.each(function(i) {
        var $that = $(this);
        $feeds.each(function(j) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (j <= i) {
                return true;//continue
            };
            if ($this.text() == $that.text()) {
                $this.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NHEKd/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `filter` function you could use an object to collect all the feed titles with their jQuery elements. The object will behave just like a `HashMap` in Java since objects can't contain duplicate keys - so duplicate feed titles are eliminated automatically.

```
var unique = { };
// Reverse elements to keep first occurence of feed title (and not the last one)
$($(".feedburnerFeedBlock li").get().reverse()).each(function(){
    // Use feed title as key and jQuery element as value
    unique[$(this).find("a").text()] = $(this);
}).hide();
// Show all unique elements
for (title in unique) {
    unique[title].show();
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/9GKBH/1/

Besides, your code doesn't work because of several reasons. Amongst others jQuery's `.html()` function only returns the HTML string of the first element in the set ([see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)).