# Can jQuery's filter method be used in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381621/jquery-function-to-get-all-unique-elements-from-an-array), there's an issue with jQuery's `filter` method in IE8- but according to [their API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the functionality's been there since 1.4, and nothing is mentioned about browser incompatibility.

Which is it?

I don't have a system with IE8 installed, my customer **will** use that version and I develop on Foxy and Chromy. The jQuery version on the client's final system is (at least) 1.7.

Comment: There's an issue with the *native* `Array.prototype.filter` method in IE8 and below. The jQuery equivalent will work fine.

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery's `.filter()` method (which will definitely work in IE8) or the native JS `Array.filter()` method (which won't, and which has nothing to do with jQuery)?

Comment: No it is not supported in IE8: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.filter

Comment: "I don't have a system with IE8 installed, my customer **will** use that version". I think I've spotted your problem. I suggest searching for "Windows XP Professional OEM" on eBay, and buying VMWare.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Or even simpler: switching IE9/10 into IE8 compat mode;)

Comment: @Christoph: simpler, yes, but unless that's what the customer's doing, you're not able to run the same software as them, and there's a chance they'll find bugs that you can't reproduce. (I've had this with a couple of IE 8 issues specifically.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer in the first article states the *native* `Array.prototype.filter` method which is a utility function on native Javascript Arrays (you could write `[].filter(...)` that way without any framework). This is not supported in IE8.

However, you want to use jQuery's `filter()` method (to filter dom nodes), which is completely safe to use in IE8;)

Comment: I'd be using jQuery's *filter*, definitely. I only reacted to your remark "to filter DOM nodes". Isn't the *filter* of jQuery suitable for **all** kinds of filtration? It seems to me that I can use it on my arrays and stuff seem to work but you got me unsure...

Comment: @Konrad sure, you can use it for any kinds of filtering. The most common case is probably filtering dom elements. Sorry for the confusion;) However most likely a plain for loop would be faster that the calling jquery filter.

Answer (score 1):

[Native JS array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is not the same as [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
If you need the native solution, you can implement a shim/shiv for IE8

IE8 does not support the native filter but DOES support jQuery's until jQuery v2

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this == null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: not needed, OP confused native and jquery's filter method (see my answer).

Comment: I know he did. But in case he wants it anyway, I gave it
@nnnnnn you mean shiv as in prison to waste IE? :)

Comment: shiv===shim since html5shiv/shim