# Distinct array of variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, distinct, distinct-values

My question is simple.
The array is claimed by a variable.

```
var array = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,,4];
```

How can I get the new array like

```
array2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: *"My question is simple"* I cannot see how when I have no idea what you are talking about. What do you think you mean be "coding in mongodb"? Is this an array within a document? Are you actually somehow referring to values in different documents in an abstract way? If you just walked up to someone with that written on a piece of paper, then do you really think they would have any idea what you mean? You need to be a lot more clear when communicating with other people.

Comment: Hi, the array is not within document. Only claimed to variable. This question do not involve collection or document. Thank you.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with either of those then you are asking about a programming language. There is no "mongodb programming language". You probably mean JavaScript, and you probably mean "within the mongo shell" which is just a JavaScript REPL of course. And when someone says "Your question is unclear" then they ( me actually ) really do mean it and you should pay attention and edit your question to explain what you mean. Of course if you want a "distinct array in JavaScript" then that's the question you ask instead. Or better yet search for it, since it's already been answered.

Comment: Are you asking how to eliminate all repeated values, or all _sequential_ repeated values?  Should `[3, 2, 2 3]` be returned as `[3, 2, 3]` or `[3, 2]` (or even `[2, 3]`)?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381621/jquery-function-to-get-all-unique-elements-from-an-array

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't even search Google or Stackoverflow before asking this question.

Comment: One liner ~ `array2 = Array.from(new Set(array)).filter(t => typeof t !== 'undefined')`

Answer (score 0):

This might help ([Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)). This answer is from above link

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

usage example:

```
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = a.filter( onlyUnique ); // returns ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

Comment: OP is clearly using JS. When answering please post a code example whenever you can.